# Rich:Calendar Set Time as Current System Time instead of Default

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm using RichFaces 3.3.3 and been trying to figure out how to set the Time portion of `Rich:Cal` to be current System date instead of the Default `12:00` where the date pattern is `dd/M/yyyy HH:mm` . I am also not interested  using `DefaultTime` attribute as its no use in my situation.

so Question is : Have i missed it or it is not possible to have current system time included when user selects a date cell?

2 - If the answer to above is **not possible** then what is the best way to implement such behaviour.

Would below be any good :

```
    <rich:calendar id="richCal1"                                
        value="#{cust.dateFrom1}"
        datePattern="dd/M/yyyy HH:mm"
        enableManualInput="true"
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/M/yyyy HH:mm" type="both"/>
        <f:validator validatorId="#{cust.dateAppend}"/>
        <f:attribute name="richCalendar" value="RichCalendar1" />
    </rich:calendar>
```

So when user selects a date, in Backbean custom validator `dateAppend` i will determine the element the trigger was fired from `using the UIComponent.getAttributes() which for above code will be richCalendar` and hence know which backbean variable to update to overwrite default Time with System time. Sounds Hacky but i don't know any other way and should work.

I'm posting here so in case the above approach is totally wrong someone can let me know or offer advice on alternatives. Thanks

### UPDATE:

The above approach won't work since Setters are called at update model not at apply request phase and therefore i cannot change the value of backbean variable when the event is fired.

there must be a way. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a custom CalendarDataModel and assign it as dataModel for the calendar.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.intercept.BypassInterceptors;
import org.richfaces.model.CalendarDataModel;
import org.richfaces.model.CalendarDataModelItem;

@Name("richCalendarDataModel")
@BypassInterceptors
public class RichCalendarDataModel implements CalendarDataModel {


    public CalendarDataModelItem[] getData(Date[] arg0) {
        RichCalendarDataItem[] date = new RichCalendarDataItem[arg0.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (Date dd : arg0) {
            Date myCustomDate = ...; //create your custom date here from original dd
            RichCalendarDataItem tmp = new RichCalendarDataItem(myCustomDate, true);
            date[i] = tmp;
            i++;
        }

        return date;
    }


    public Object getToolTip(Date arg0) {
        ...
    }

}
```

calendarDataModelItem:

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.richfaces.model.CalendarDataModelItem;

public class RichCalendarDataItem implements CalendarDataModelItem {

private Date data;

private boolean enabled;

public RichCalendarDataItem(Date dd, boolean en) {
    data = dd;
    enabled = en;
}

public int getDay() {
    return 0;
}

public Object getData() {
    return data;
}

public String getStyleClass() {
    return null;
}

public Object getToolTip() {
    return null;
}

public boolean hasToolTip() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the heads up . i look into `UICalendar.java` source found here (http://goo.gl/Phf0z) and there it s ---> 

   `/**
   * Returns default value of "defaultTime" attribute
   * @return default value of "defaultTime" attribute
   */
   protected Object getDefaultValueOfDefaultTime() {
    Calendar calendar = getCalendar();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    
    return calendar.getTime();
   }`
   
Thank you so much